# pgfplots: Read expression from file

Tags: pgfplots, plot, gnuplot

For my lab reports I often have to do complex fitting and transformations to my data (like fitting cauchy distributions or FFT). Fitting with `gnuplot` sometimes fails and including it directly in the `\addplot`-command is a real pain. For example I can't set different linetypes for different plots in

```
\addplot gnuplot[raw gnuplot] {
  plot sin(x), cos(x);
}
```

They will both have the same linetype. So if I do complex fitting, I can't do it within one `\addplot` command, which forces me to repeat all variables and stuff. That's why I want to fall back to external fitting. Therefore it would be very useful, if one was able to read a mathematical expression from a file, e.g.

```
\addplot expression[from file] {math.dat}
```

where `math.dat` yields the expression in the expected format.

Is that possible with the current versions of `pgfplots`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write one or more expressions to a table and access the table's elements using `\pgfplotstablegetelem`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
    expression
    x^2
    x^3
}\loadedtable

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{expression}\of{\loadedtable}
    % \pgfplotsretval is frequently overwritten.
    % copy its value to "\expression":
    \let\expression=\pgfplotsretval

    \addplot {\expression};

    \pgfplotstablegetelem{1}{expression}\of{\loadedtable}
    \let\expression=\pgfplotsretval

    \addplot {\expression};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My example contains inline table data which is not quite your use-case.

However, you can also write

```
\pgfplotstableread{math.dat}\loadedtable
```

or even

```
\pgfplotstablegetelem{1}{expression}\of{math.dat}
```

pgfplots will automatically check if the argument is a loaded table.